# Nearby permission requested multiple times

Tags: google-nearby

Is there a way for the user's acceptance of nearby permission to only be asked ONCE? I have an app where the permission is asked every few days (seemingly) when the app is opened.

I enable it with this code (also used to enable Google sign in):

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addApi(Nearby.MESSAGES_API)
            .build();
```

Since nearby permission request is built into Neraby's auto management, that's the only code I was using. There's a **chance** that it's not actually asking for it multiple times and I'm just having a hard time separating the times it's asked after I've pushed code changes from times a few days have passed and it asks though. I've got it on multiple phones and it's a hobby project, so it's not a constant item I'm checking.

Comment: Is this an app you've seen on the Play Store, or one you've written yourself? If it's the latter, can you share the API call you're making?

Comment: @WilliamHarmon I've updated the question with my code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen this happen on our devices (I work on the Nearby team at Google).

The only case I know of where the dialog will reappear is if the app is uninstalled / reinstalled, or if the app loses its permissions in Settings > Google > Nearby > [gear icon].

Comment: Thank you! Since you're on that team, is there any way to provide an option NOT to use sound for nearby? Motorola phones (both the Z2 and G4) emit an audible sound that's been annoying to one of my test users.

Comment: Yup, there is. I'll grab you a code snippet when I'm in the office. I'll also file a bug to look into those 2 phones to see if we can't do something about that.

Comment: subscribe(listener, new SubscribeOptions.Builder().setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY).build());

publish(message, new PublishOptions.Builder().setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY).build());

Comment: Thank you, Xylthe! I didn't think you could publish with BLE_ONLY but maybe I was looking at old documentation.

Comment: One other piece of feedback: when I keep my app running for a long time on a test device, it seems to kill the audio service on the phone. It no longer recognizes a headset plugged in, no sound comes from the speakers, and the microphone doesn't work. Resetting the phone gets them working again. It's a first gen Pixel.

Comment: My app was already using the BLE_ONLY strategy for subscribe but changing it for the publisher caused it to not publish with the error that you cannot have TTL_SECONDS_INFINITE for publish. This aligns with the documentation I had read on BLE_ONLY.